# Swift 4 Convert simple array to nested array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, swift4

I receive a Json feed which is decoded to a simple array... I want to convert it to a nested multi dimensional  array.  the syntax of how to loop through my animalArray and insert mammals into the mammalArray is my goal  See code

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


// JSON is decoded to a simple Struct
struct Animals {
    var category: String
    var animalName: String
}

// simulating Animals returned to JSON
var lion = Animals(category: "wild", animalName: "lion")
var hippo = Animals(category: "wild", animalName: "hippo")
var bear = Animals(category: "wild", animalName: "bear")
var dog = Animals(category: "house", animalName: "dpg")
var cat = Animals(category: "house", animalName: "cat")
var rabbit = Animals(category: "house", animalName: "rabbit")

// simulate the  animalArry received by decoded Json
var animalArray = [Animals]()
animalArray.append(lion)
animalArray.append(hippo)
animalArray.append(dog)
animalArray.append(bear)
animalArray.append(cat)
animalArray.append(rabbit)

// Goal is to convert  animal Array to structure of mammals and mammalsArray
struct mammals {
    var animalResides: String  // (category)  wild
    var critters : [String]     // (animalName) [ lion, hippo, bear]
}
var MammalArray = [mammals]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution:

First of all struct names are supposed to start with a capital letter and variable names with a lowercase letter.

```
struct Mammals {
    var animalResides: String  // (category)  wild
    var critters : [String]     // (animalName) [ lion, hippo, bear]
}

var mammalArray = [Mammals]()
```

Map the array to its categories and create a `Set` to get unique values

```
let categories = Set(animalArray.map{ $0.category }) // Set(["house", "wild"])
```

In the loop filter `animalArray` by category respectively and create the `Mammals` instance with the category as `animalResides` and the mapped names of the filtered items as `critters`

```
for category in categories {
    let filtered = animalArray.filter({$0.category == category})
    mammalArray.append(Mammals(animalResides: category, critters: filtered.map({$0.animalName})))
}

print(mammalArray)
```

Comment: Vadian, thanks for the elegant solution.  I had tried something similar...but as a newbie the syntax sometimes gets the best of me.